# jQuery not working on ajax pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am using jQuery to display a overlay div on hover for my products. However I also have AJAX pagination. The overlay works fine on "page 1", but on "page 2" it doesn't.

The overlay JS:

```
jQuery(function () {

jQuery('.proditem').hover(function () {
    jQuery('.productoverlay', this).stop().css({
        "opacity": 0.3
    }, "fast");
},

function () {
    jQuery('.productoverlay', this).stop().css({
        "opacity": 0
    }, "fast");
});
});
```

The ajax that calls "page 2" to display on same page.

```
jQuery.ias({
    container : '.category-products',
    item: '.proditem',
    pagination: '.toolbar .pager',
    next: '.next',
    loader: '<img src="images/ajaxscroll/loader.gif" /> Loading more products'
});
```

Not sure if this is enough information or not? The ajax pagination is a plugin.

Please help, maybe something simple I'm missing?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: All the code posted looks strange. The `css()` method does not have a duration and it looks like you should be using `animate()` as that is the syntax you're using. The second piece of code for the ajax call is impossible to figure out without knowing more about the plugin used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('body').on({
    'mouseover':  function () {
        jQuery('.productoverlay', this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0.3);
    },
    'mouseout': function () {
        jQuery('.productoverlay', this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 0.3);
    }
}, '.proditem');
```

This code will work for elements that doesn't exist yet.

As it's suggested in the comment below - the better way to do this is to replace 'body' to the closest parent element for '.proditem' that isn't changing after AJAX-paging.

Don't forget to up [Sinetheta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848249/sinetheta)'s comment for useful fixes :)

Comment: This is the right answer, the only 2 suggestions I would make are using [.fadeTo(duration, opacity)](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead of css opacity for cross browser compatibility. And binding the the closest "persistent" element instead of `<body>`, maybe there is a `<div id="container">` of some kind?

Comment: Thanks, Sinetheta updated my answer.
Mike Meade, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery for the overlay is only executed when the page is loaded. So it only works on elements that are on the page at that time. When you replace them with new elements, which you do when you fetch the second page using AJAX, you'll have to run the initialization code again, so it also works on the new elements.

Comment: Ah ok, how would I go about running it again when the new elements are loaded?

Comment: Put the initialization code in a separate function. Call this function both when the DOM is ready and when the AJAX call succeeds. The latter may be a problem, because I think you don't execute the AJAX calls yourself. I'm not very familiar with this pagination functionality, but now you know what the problem is, maybe you can find a feature that allows you to run a function after a new page is loaded.

Comment: Apparently you are using the [Infinite Ajax Scroll](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin), which is not quite pagination. Anyway, on the comments on that page I linked, one Barty mentioned the same problem. The solution: apparently, an onRenderComplete event exists that allows you to take specific action when additional content is loaded.